# Windows does not start?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

Well I checked and SO are the two Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 Ultimate.
but after restart the screen goes black for about 15 seconds and then start Ubuntu.
Even not to do to bring up the Grub.
Since the probe Boot-disk-repair-tool and this is the result I get:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729018/

thanks

Comment: try the second option in this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

When ubuntu is installed it overites the bootloader and installs GRUB (the software that offers you the OS selection at boot)

First you need to reinstall ubuntu to have a working OS which you can make the changes on.

To add windows 7 to the GRUB menu:

First, you will need to know which of the NTFS partitions. You can test by mounting each and see what they contain. Generally you're looking for whatever contains Windows/ .

Once you know which partition that is (i.e., /dev/sda5), reduce that number by one. That number will be replaced with the "4" in "rootnoverify (hd0,4)"

Then enter this into /boot/grub/grub.conf [if that doesn't show up, /boot/grub/menu.lst]

```
title Windows
rootnoverify (hd0,4)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```